# Crosshair / x value tooltip for linear scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Check out this block by d3noob.

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/6eb506b129f585ce5c8a

It was originally designed for a date formatted x axis. Whereas both my x and y axes are linear. What I'm trying to do is use this tooltip style for a linear x / linear y scatterplot with a trendline. I'd like to have this kind of tooltip/crosshair to go along the x axis values as the trendline ascends in my graph, just like the graph in the above block. Actually on his blog, someone asked a similar question, how to make it work for an ordinal scale, but he answers back with "That is uncharted territory."

So I thought to myself, aw, it can't be that hard. That was before I took a close look at the code and before I spent hours tweaking this and that. So I now have a healthier respect for this thing, it's not as easy as it looks.

I believe the most complicated part in changing it to linear scale is the following:

```
function mousemove() {
            var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
                i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
                d0 = data[i - 1],
                d1 = data[i],
                d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
```

Can someone post a block of this tooltip working within a linear scaled x axis? I'd love to see how you do it. I've tried lots of things (in vain), even the midpoint formula haha. In hindsight, I realize that was a stupid idea, but I was really blanking out on how to make sense of the code.

Any graph is ok, as long as it uses that tooltip.

Thanks a billion,

fyi, I know it may be a tall order to have someone create a gist/block for this, but I believe having a functional example block can reach out to many and let them learn by example. Additionally, linear scales are very popular and having this tooltip/crosshair system working for these kind of scales will be a great addition for the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what part you are having trouble with.

I took d3noob's example and converted the "date" to numeric:

```
date,close
0,606.98
10,614.48
20,617.62
30,609.86
40,599.55
50,618.63
60,629.32
70,624.31
80,633.68
90,636.23
100,628.44
110,626.20
```

I changed the scale:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
```

I then "fixed" the `data.forEach` to remove the date coercion:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = +d.date; //<-- treat date as number
    d.close = +d.close; 
});
```

And finally removed the `formatDate` calls in the mousemove.

Everything still works, [here is a link to it running.](http://plnkr.co/edit/ShQxephCjXNyTN1yseKN?p=preview)

---

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->    
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });
    
// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var lineSvg = svg.append("g"); 

var focus = svg.append("g") 
    .style("display", "none");

// Get the data
//d3.csv("atad.csv", function(error, data) {
  
    var data = [{"date":"0","close":"606.98"},{"date":"10","close":"614.48"},{"date":"20","close":"617.62"},{"date":"30","close":"609.86"},{"date":"40","close":"599.55"},{"date":"50","close":"618.63"},{"date":"60","close":"629.32"},{"date":"70","close":"624.31"},{"date":"80","close":"633.68"},{"date":"90","close":"636.23"},{"date":"100","close":"628.44"},{"date":"110","close":"626.20"},{"date":"120","close":"622.77"},{"date":"130","close":"605.23"},{"date":"140","close":"580.13"},{"date":"150","close":"543.70"},{"date":"160","close":"443.34"},{"date":"170","close":"345.44"},{"date":"180","close":"234.98"},{"date":"190","close":"166.70"},{"date":"200","close":"130.28"},{"date":"210","close":"99.00"},{"date":"220","close":"89.70"},{"date":"230","close":"67.00"},{"date":"240","close":"53.98"},{"date":"250","close":"58.13"}];
    
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = +d.date;
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    lineSvg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

   // append the x line
    focus.append("line")
        .attr("class", "x")
        .style("stroke", "blue")
        .style("stroke-dasharray", "3,3")
        .style("opacity", 0.5)
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("y2", height);

    // append the y line
    focus.append("line")
        .attr("class", "y")
        .style("stroke", "blue")
        .style("stroke-dasharray", "3,3")
        .style("opacity", 0.5)
        .attr("x1", width)
        .attr("x2", width);

    // append the circle at the intersection
    focus.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "y")
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("r", 4);

    // place the value at the intersection
    focus.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y1")
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", "3.5px")
        .style("opacity", 0.8)
        .attr("dx", 8)
        .attr("dy", "-.3em");
    focus.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y2")
        .attr("dx", 8)
        .attr("dy", "-.3em");

    // place the date at the intersection
    focus.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y3")
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", "3.5px")
        .style("opacity", 0.8)
        .attr("dx", 8)
        .attr("dy", "1em");
    focus.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y4")
        .attr("dx", 8)
        .attr("dy", "1em");
    
    // append the rectangle to capture mouse
    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("pointer-events", "all")
        .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
        .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
        .on("mousemove", mousemove);

    function mousemove() {
  var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
      i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
      d0 = data[i - 1],
      d1 = data[i],
      d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;

  focus.select("circle.y")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," +
                           y(d.close) + ")");

  focus.select("text.y1")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," +
                           y(d.close) + ")")
      .text(d.close);

  focus.select("text.y2")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," +
                           y(d.close) + ")")
      .text(d.close);

  focus.select("text.y3")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," +
                           y(d.close) + ")")
      .text(d.date);

  focus.select("text.y4")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," +
                           y(d.close) + ")")
      .text(d.date);

  focus.select(".x")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," +
                           y(d.close) + ")")
                 .attr("y2", height - y(d.close));

  focus.select(".y")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + width * -1 + "," +
                           y(d.close) + ")")
                 .attr("x2", width + width);
 }

//});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the step by step explanation.You helped me understand why treat date as number and that part of the mouse move function need to be changed. Problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/ayta89cz/5/

In this fiddle I'm just using `d3.mouse()` to get the position of the mouse over the transparent rectangle, and using two dashed lines for the crosshair. You can easily convert these values to the relative x-scale and y-scale values. I hardcoded the math here because I knew the slope of the trendline I just created, but you have to modify the math according to your trendline.

Comment: You're right, it's easy to apply to other graphs. And it's cool because most crosshair templates are date formatted. I'll bookmark that page, even though I like the styling of the original, the concept is the main thing.