# Cross Hairs component throws error, dataset specific?

Tags: d3.js

I have made multiple graphs that have a cross hairs component. I usually model them after [this block](http://bl.ocks.org/mikehadlow/93b471e569e31af07cd3). It's not easy to tinker with unless you are very familiar with the intricacies of it. This is a simplified version just to illustrate my predicament. The only complicated thing about it is I'm using a `linear` scale as opposed to the conventional `time` scale. You may learn more about that in: [Crosshair / x value tooltip for linear scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996352/crosshair-x-value-tooltip-for-linear-scale).

Without further ado, here is my snippet with hard-coded data. This dataset, for whatever reason, always doesn't work with my crosshairs component (either that or my user-error is equally systematic).

```js
var margins = {left:50, right:0, top:30, bottom:40};
var padding = 80;
var graphOne = {width:500, height:500};

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', graphOne.width+margins.left+margins.right+padding)
    .attr('height', graphOne.height);

var rawData =    [
     {'fpr': '1', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.97', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.94', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.85', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.79', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.76', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.61', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.5', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.3824', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.3529', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.3529', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2941', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2941', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2941', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2647', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2647', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2647', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2647', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2647', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2647', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2647', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2353', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2353', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2059', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2059', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.1765', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.1471', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.1471', 'tpr': '0.9655'},
     {'fpr': '0.0882', 'tpr': '0.9655'},
     {'fpr': '0.0882', 'tpr': '0.9655'},
     {'fpr': '0.0882', 'tpr': '0.9655'},
     {'fpr': '0.0882', 'tpr': '0.9655'},
     {'fpr': '0.0882', 'tpr': '0.9655'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.9655'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.9655'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8621'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8621'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8621'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8621'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.7586'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.5862'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.5517'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.4828'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.3448'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.3103'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.1379'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.1034'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.07'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0'}
   ];

   var data = rawData.map(function(d) {
     return { X: +d.fpr, Y: +d.tpr,}
   });

  var xScaleOne = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.X; }))
    .range([0, graphOne.width]);

  var yScaleOne = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.Y; }))
    .range([graphOne.height-margins.bottom-margins.top, 0]);

  var xAxisOne = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScaleOne).orient('bottom');
  var yAxisOne = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScaleOne).orient('left');

  var xAxisOneNodes = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (margins.left) + ',' + (graphOne.height - margins.bottom) + ')')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .call(xAxisOne);

  var yAxisOneNodes = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (margins.left) + ',' + (margins.top) + ')')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(yAxisOne);

  var graphOneGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (margins.left) + ',' + margins.top + ')');

  var lineOne = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) { return xScaleOne(d.X); })
      .y(function(d) { return yScaleOne(d.Y); });

  var diagonal = graphOneGroup.append('line')
    .attr({x1:xScaleOne(0), x2:xScaleOne(1), y1:yScaleOne(0), y2:yScaleOne(1)})
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-dasharray', '4,4')
    .attr('stroke-width',3);

    graphOneGroup.append('path')
      .datum(data)
      .attr('d',lineOne)
      .attr('fill','none')
      .attr('stroke', '#000')
      .attr('stroke-width', '3px');
//focus start
    var focus = graphOneGroup.append('g').style('display', 'none');
    var xDomain = d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d[0]; });
    var yDomain = d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d[1]; });
    focus.append("line")
        .attr("id", "verticalFocus")
        .style("stroke", "gray")
        .style("stroke-width", "3px")
        .style("stroke-dasharray", "5,5")
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("y2", graphOne.height-margins.top-margins.bottom);

    focus.append("line")
        .attr("id", "horizontalFocus")
        .style("stroke", "gray")
        .style("stroke-width", "3px")
        .style("stroke-dasharray", "5,5")
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .attr("x1", graphOne.width)
        .attr("x2",  graphOne.width);

    focus.append("circle")
        .attr("id", "circleFocus")
        .style("fill", "#376c9b")
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", "3px")
        .attr("r", 5);

    var bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return +d[0]; }).left;

    graphOneGroup.append("rect")
        .attr("width", graphOne.width)
        .attr("height",graphOne.height-margins.top-margins.bottom)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("pointer-events", "all")
        .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
        .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
        .on("mousemove", mousemove);

    function mousemove() {
      var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
      var mouseValue = xScaleOne.invert(mouse[0]);
      var i = bisect(data, mouseValue);

      var d0 = data[i-1];
      var d1 = data[i];
      console.log(d0)
      console.log(d1)
      var d = mouseValue - d0[0] > d1[0] - mouseDate ? d1 : d0;

      var x = xScaleOne(d[0]);
      var y = yScaleOne(d[1]);

      focus.select('#horizontalFocus')
        .attr('x1', x).attr('y1', yScaleOne(yDomain[0]))
        .attr('x2', x).attr('y2', yScaleOne(yDomain[1]));

      focus.select('#verticalFocus')
          .attr('x1', xScaleOne(xDomain[0])).attr('y1', y)
          .attr('x2', xScaleOne(xDomain[1])).attr('y2', y);

      focus.select('#circleFocus')
          .attr('cx',x)
          .attr('cy',y);
        }
```

```css
g.x.axis, g.y.axis {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Play;
}

.tick line {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#000;
  stroke-width:1px;
}

.domain {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#000;
  stroke-width:.25em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

I tried to indicate the focus/crosshairs section using comments. You will also notice some strange results in the console log. `d0` is being read as undefined. This seems to be throwing the calculation off every time the mouse moves. I am pretty sure my event-listener rect is positioned correctly; as undefined values can occur in the margins as was mentioned in a similar crosshairs question: [Cannot read property "0" of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272459/cannot-read-property-0-of-undefined). The other moral of that story was not to make a new line after `return` in the bisect function, which I was mindful of.

**Question:** Why is my `d0` undefined? My crosshair component is almost identical to the example block I posted with the minor exception of using a `linear` scale. I was careful to adjust the necessary sections of the code to account for that. I used linear scales before with this system; my hunch is that this data set brings out a bug in the code, or has some other property that my code is not robust to -- whatever that is, I can't find the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to your question: **Why is `d0` undefined?** is the wrong usage of the `bisect` function.

Here are the **docs** for `d3.bisect`: https://github.com/d3/d3-array#bisect

If you look at the usage and using it for your data, it'd be this: `var bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return +d.X; }).left;`

AND one major thing (it's even mentioned in the docs) is that this `d3.bisect` assumes the array to be a sorted one which in your case isn't. When I console logged the data, I found out that it's in the reverse order and so just used `data.reverse()` to pass it to the `d3 bisector`.

Rest were a few minor changes which I assume you might've copied from the example blocks that you refer to.

For example: In the line, `.attr('x1', x).attr('y1', yScaleOne(yDomain[0]))`, `yDomain` is missing in your case. And same is the case for `xDomain` used in the next few lines.

Adding the above and fixing the errors, here's a snippet of the same:

```js
var margins = {left:50, right:0, top:30, bottom:40};
var padding = 80;
var graphOne = {width:500, height:500};

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', graphOne.width+margins.left+margins.right+padding)
    .attr('height', graphOne.height);

var rawData =    [
     {'fpr': '1', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.97', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.94', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.85', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.79', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.76', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.61', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.5', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.3824', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.3529', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.3529', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2941', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2941', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2941', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2647', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2647', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2647', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2647', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2647', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2647', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2647', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2353', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2353', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2059', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.2059', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.1765', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.1471', 'tpr': '1'},
     {'fpr': '0.1471', 'tpr': '0.9655'},
     {'fpr': '0.0882', 'tpr': '0.9655'},
     {'fpr': '0.0882', 'tpr': '0.9655'},
     {'fpr': '0.0882', 'tpr': '0.9655'},
     {'fpr': '0.0882', 'tpr': '0.9655'},
     {'fpr': '0.0882', 'tpr': '0.9655'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.9655'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.9655'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0588', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8966'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8621'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8621'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8621'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8621'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.8276'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0.0294', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.7931'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.7586'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.5862'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.5517'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.4828'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.3448'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.3103'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.1379'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.1034'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0.07'},
     {'fpr': '0', 'tpr': '0'}
   ];

   var data = rawData.map(function(d) {
     return { X: +d.fpr, Y: +d.tpr,}
   });

 data = data.reverse(); // sorted the data
  var xScaleOne = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.X; }))
    .range([0, graphOne.width]);

  var yScaleOne = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.Y; }))
    .range([graphOne.height-margins.bottom-margins.top, 0]);

  var xAxisOne = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScaleOne).orient('bottom');
  var yAxisOne = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScaleOne).orient('left');

  var xAxisOneNodes = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (margins.left) + ',' + (graphOne.height - margins.bottom) + ')')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .call(xAxisOne);

  var yAxisOneNodes = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (margins.left) + ',' + (margins.top) + ')')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(yAxisOne);

  var graphOneGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (margins.left) + ',' + margins.top + ')');

  var lineOne = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) { return xScaleOne(d.X); })
      .y(function(d) { return yScaleOne(d.Y); });

  var diagonal = graphOneGroup.append('line')
    .attr({x1:xScaleOne(0), x2:xScaleOne(1), y1:yScaleOne(0), y2:yScaleOne(1)})
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-dasharray', '4,4')
    .attr('stroke-width',3);

    graphOneGroup.append('path')
      .datum(data)
      .attr('d',lineOne)
      .attr('fill','none')
      .attr('stroke', '#000')
      .attr('stroke-width', '3px');
//focus start
    var focus = graphOneGroup.append('g').style('display', 'none');
    var xDomain = d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d[0]; });
    var yDomain = d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d[1]; });
    focus.append("line")
        .attr("id", "verticalFocus")
        .style("stroke", "gray")
        .style("stroke-width", "3px")
        .style("stroke-dasharray", "5,5")
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("y2", graphOne.height-margins.top-margins.bottom);

    focus.append("line")
        .attr("id", "horizontalFocus")
        .style("stroke", "gray")
        .style("stroke-width", "3px")
        .style("stroke-dasharray", "5,5")
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .attr("x1", graphOne.width)
        .attr("x2",  graphOne.width);

    focus.append("circle")
        .attr("id", "circleFocus")
        .style("fill", "#376c9b")
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", "3px")
        .attr("r", 5);

    var bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return +d.X; }).left;

    graphOneGroup.append("rect")
        .attr("width", graphOne.width)
        .attr("height",graphOne.height-margins.top-margins.bottom)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("pointer-events", "all")
        .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
        .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
        .on("mousemove", mousemove);

    function mousemove() {
      var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
      var mouseValue = xScaleOne.invert(mouse[0]);
      var i = bisect(data, mouseValue);

      var d0 = data[i-1];
      var d1 = data[i];
     // console.log(d0)
     // console.log(d1)
      var d = mouseValue - d0.X > d1.X - mouseValue ? d1 : d0;

      var x = xScaleOne(d.X);
      var y = yScaleOne(d.Y);

      focus.select('#horizontalFocus')
        .attr('x1', x).attr('y1', yScaleOne(yScaleOne.domain()[0]))
        .attr('x2', x).attr('y2', yScaleOne(yScaleOne.domain()[1]));

      focus.select('#verticalFocus')
          .attr('x1', xScaleOne(xScaleOne.domain()[0])).attr('y1', y)
          .attr('x2', xScaleOne(xScaleOne.domain()[1])).attr('y2', y);

      focus.select('#circleFocus')
          .attr('cx',x)
          .attr('cy',y);
        }
```

```css
g.x.axis, g.y.axis {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Play;
}

.tick line {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#000;
  stroke-width:1px;
}

.domain {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#000;
  stroke-width:.25em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

Relevant changes:

```
data = data.reverse(); // sorted the data
...
...
...  
function mousemove() {
 ...
 focus.select('#horizontalFocus')
    .attr('x1', x).attr('y1', yScaleOne(yScaleOne.domain()[0]))
    .attr('x2', x).attr('y2', yScaleOne(yScaleOne.domain()[1]));

 focus.select('#verticalFocus')
      .attr('x1', xScaleOne(xScaleOne.domain()[0])).attr('y1', y)
      .attr('x2', xScaleOne(xScaleOne.domain()[1])).attr('y2', y);
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Wow, you did it! I'm very excited to get the graph up and running with crosshairs finally. Can't thank you enough! There is one thing that still puzzles me; the `x` and `y` attributes. For example, with the horizontal focus crosshair line we set its `x` attributes normally, but the `y` attributes have to be retrieved through `yScaleOne(yScaleOne.domain()[0]))`. Is that because we don't actually know the `y` value, and we have to retrieve it via the index we got through `bisect`? Not sure about those parts. Everything else makes perfect sense though.

Comment: You're welcome. For example, for the horizontal focus: `y1 = yScaleOne(yScaleOne.domain()[0]))` and `y2 = yScaleOne(yScaleOne.domain()[1]))` simply means from 0 to the entire height and similarly `x1 and x2` for `#verticalFocus` means from 0 to entire width. If you want the lines to extend from 0 to the point on the line (circle), try changing `y2` for **#horizontalFocus** to `y` (computed y) and `x2` for **#verticalFocus** to `x` (computed x). Glad I could help.